# exec.Command добавляет спецсимволы

Tags: golang

Пытаюсь выполнить команду для компилирования Golang программы, код:

```
var buildCommand = fmt.Sprintf("go build %s %s main.go", `-v -a -x`, `-ldflags="-w -s"`);

var cmd = exec.Command(buildCommand)
var err = cmd.Run()
```

Если я выведу переменную `buildCommand` я получу:

`go build -v -a -x -ldflags="-w -s" main.go`

но при запуске самой программы-билдера будет выдавать: `exec: "go build -v -a -x -ldflags=\"-w -s\" main.go`, то есть добавляются вот такие знаки `"\ \"`, причем сам `exec.Command` это добавляет, как это можно исправить?

Comment: Старайтесь давать минимальный рабочий код который можно проверять на прямую.

Comment: У вас первая ошибка вы `exec.Command()` неверно используете. Первый аргумент должет быть имя команды т.е. `go` а вы даёте `go build -v -a -x -ldflags="-w -s" main.go`. А далее `\` уже результат построения строки для ошибки. Посмотрите примеры https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверное вы хотите что-то вроде этого.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    buildCommand := []string{"build", "-o", "new.exe", "-v", "-a", "-x", "-ldflags=-w -s", "main.go"}
    cmd := exec.Command("go", buildCommand...)
    out, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "%v\n%s\n", err, string(out))
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", string(out))
    }

}
```

Попробуйте объединить флажки вместе к примеру вместо `... "-v", "-a" ...` -> `... "-v -a" ...`. И постарайтесь понять ошибки.

Удачи

Comment: Спасибо! Понял свою ошибку)